# Flutter creat pdf file with different page size and font size

Tags: pdf, flutter, size

Here with the code to create a pdf file for flutter. I am using plugin [pdf 1.0.6](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pdf#-example-tab-).

My questions:

- How to create a pdf file width 75mm with auto height to fit the
  content?
- How to create multi lines of text with different font size?

  ```
  PDFDocument _generateDocument() {
  final pdf = new PDFDocument(deflate: zlib.encode);
  final page = new PDFPage(pdf, pageFormat: PDFPageFormat.A4);
  final g = page.getGraphics();
  final font = new PDFFont(pdf);
  final top = page.pageFormat.height;

  g.setColor(new PDFColor(0.0, 1.0, 1.0));
  g.drawRect(50.0 * PDFPageFormat.MM, top - 80.0 * PDFPageFormat.MM,
      100.0 * PDFPageFormat.MM, 50.0 * PDFPageFormat.MM);
  g.fillPath();

  g.setColor(new PDFColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3));
  g.drawString(font, 12.0, "Hello World!", 10.0 * PDFPageFormat.MM,
      top - 10.0 * PDFPageFormat.MM);

  return pdf;
  ```

  }

Comment: Seems like most of this has changed and is very different now. What does the page look like with this code?

Comment: What hasn't changed is this package's apparent inability to create a page to fit the content length which is the question

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to update to the latest version `pdf: ^1.4.` as a lot has changed on how to build a pdf.

- For the format size I would try  PdfPageFormat.undefined or in your case PdfPageFormat(75, double.infinity)

https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/blob/78232de1f962ea04c7e950d0f737417a35863071/pdf/lib/src/page_format.dart#L49

- For the multiline with different size I would use the new way of creating a pdf that uses widgets. See the example:

https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/blob/master/pdf/example/main.dart

As simple as

```dart
pdf.addPage(Page(
    pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
    build: (Context context) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Hello World', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
      ); // Center
    })); // Page
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
void createAndSavePdf(){
final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
 final pdf = pw.Document();
//you can user layout builder to find height
// or use ImageInfo to find Image Height  
final customPageSize = PdfPageFormat(75, height, marginAll: 0);
  pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
          pageFormat: customPageSize,
          build: (pw.Context context) {
            return pw.Center(
              child: pw.Image(image, fit: pw.BoxFit.fitHeight),
            ); // Center
          }));
      final pdfFile = await pdfDoc.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
}
```